# fancybox to show a specific folder of images

Tags: jquery

I have 8 folders of images each folder is named different and the images in each folder are named different from the other folder.

Example:

Folder named A all images inside are named A-1.jpg, A-2.jpg and so on...
Next folder named B with the same naming ( B-1.jpg and so on ).

I want to use a image on page for each folder to be the link to activate a gallery of the images, in each folder, that corresponds with each image on page without having to do this.

```
<a class="fancybox" href="fancybox/A/A-1.jpg">
    <img src="fancybox/A/A-1.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>

<div class="hidden">
    <a class="fancybox" href="fancybox/A/A-2.jpg">
        <img src="fancybox/A/A-2.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="fancybox/A/A-3.jpg">
        <img src="fancybox/A/A-3.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
</div>
```

jscript

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding : 0
    });
```

css

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

Rather than have to list all the images in the html...
Is there a way to just target the images by name and not extension (.jpg)?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery  you can use `document.createElement("a")` combined with  `$(var).prop()` to assign the property tags like `src` and `alt`

All you neeed is to do a loop or something that loops through all the letters then all the numbers and combines them together into a function like the one i have created in the snippet below.

I'm assuming your asking how to make a gallery even though the question currently asks if its possible only

```js
function create_image(imgLetter, imgNum) {

  var container = document.querySelector("#container"); // container
  var link = document.createElement("a"); // make a new a tag
  var img = document.createElement("img"); // make an img tag

  $(link).addClass("fancybox"); // add class to a tag

  /* create the string for the link HREF part by using "" and + with parameters from function*/
  $(link).prop("href", "fancybox/" + imgLetter + "/" + imgLetter + "-" + imgNum + ".jpg");  

  
  $(img).prop("src", $(link).prop("href")); // src="" part to match HREF
  $(img).prop("alt", "");

  $(img).appendTo(link); // add image to link
  $(link).appendTo(container);  // add link to container
}

var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"];

for (var L = 0; L < letters.length; L++) {
  var letter = letters[L];
  for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    create_image(letter, i);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Mike that really confused me.

Comment: Mike that really confused me. Right now I have a thumb on page and when it's clicked I want it to open a gallery from a folder in this case "children" the thumb is named thumb.jpg the images in folder to use are images/children/children-001.jpg and so on through children-020.jpg

<div class="entry-thumbnail"> <img src="images/thumb/children.jpg" alt="" />
                    <span class=""><i class=""></i></span>
                </div>
the span was changed from template so it won't show hover effect overlay and fa symbol

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow isnt really a code writing service - its a website where you can provide your non-working code and then receive help/suggestions on how to fix it or improve it.   I answered your question at the end which was  `"is there a way to target images by name and not extension?"`  to which I explained how to do that.  Statements starting with `"I want..."`  are summarily ignored here.